# Use Jenkinsfile environment variable inside called build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Let's say I've got a Jenkinsfile that looks kinda like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        FOO = "bar"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps  {
                 main: {
                    build 'foo-job'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I use the value of `FOO` inside the shell script for `foo-job`? I've tried `${FOO}` and `$FOO` (empty), as well as `${env.FOO}` (bad substitution, apparently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the job `foo-job` parameterized? you cannot just simply pass environment variables to downstream jobs by just setting it in the pipeline. In your case you would have call the job `foo-job` as:

```
build(job: 'foo-job', parameters: [string(name: 'FOO', value: 'FOO')])
```

Here `FOO` is the input parameter of type string of job `foo-job`. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/ for details

Comment: you should pass parameters this way `build(job: 'foo-job', parameters: [string(name: 'FOO', value: 'FOO')])`

Comment: I'd reached this point, but I'd hoped there was a better way. Ah well, apparently not.